# Can a) and b) real components of an complex equation?

Tags: complex-analysis, partial-differential-equations, complex-numbers, cauchy-riemann-equations

I have a problem somewhere ...  I missed a point..

So given are following equations: (with $C \to R$)

- (i)  $a(z) = x^2 - y^2$
- (ii) $b(z) = x^2 + y^2$

And I am supposed to find out if those equations could be the real component of an complex equation ($C \to C$)
I used the Cauchy Riemann equation which gave me

- (i) $2x=0$ and $-2y=0$
- (ii) $2x=0$ and $2y=0$

Both just work for $x = y = 0$

But this would mean $z = 0$ right? So neither of them can be a component of an complex equation (as in complex differentiable function) right?

Comment: What you probably mean is if $a$ or $b$ can be the real part of an *analytic/holomorphic* function. But how did you come up with the equations $2x=0$ and $-2y = 0$??

Comment: as said I used the CR equations.. with the whole u(x,y) and v(x,y) but v(x,y) is 0 since we want to know about the real component.. And the exercise cleary states: 'find out if a or b can be a real component of a complex differental function in C'

Comment: OK, so you mean a complex differentiable function. That is not mentioned in the question. But *how* did you use the CR equations. There must be an error in your calculations.

Comment: To amplify what Martin said: for a), let $u(x,y)=x^2-y^2$, and see if you can find a $v(x,y)$ so that u and v satisfy CR. For b), do the same, but with u being $x^2+y^2$.

Comment: v isn't zero, it's an unknown function you need to try to solve for.

Comment: but the exercise doesn't care about the imaginary part? I should show if a or b can be in an complex function as the real component?

Comment: It cares about it; it just doesn't know it. And it wants you to care about it too (:-)), and it wants you to find it, (if you can).

Comment: v should be 0 since there is no i in the equation at all which should mean the imaginary part should be iy = 0

Comment: Oh, and yes "I should show if a or b can be in an complex function as the real component" is exactly right.

Comment: I just got more confused tbh :(

Comment: Suppose i asked you "Can $1$ be the real part of a square root of $2i$?", what would you do?

Comment: but sqrt(2i) isnt real? its the imaginary part of z and not the real...

Comment: Again: Please show (in your question, not in the comments) *how* you applied the CR equations. We cannot tell where your error is until we see what you did (wrong).

Comment: Yes, sqrt(2i) isn't real, it has to be imaginary. Let's step back - can you write me an imaginary number that has a real part 1? Just pick some arbitrary one.

Comment: differentiate the function a(z) with respect to x is 2x and to y is -2y and as i stated  the imaginary part is 0, so it is its derive...

Comment: The imaginary part is not zero.

Comment: why not? as far as I learned there need to be an i somewhere to be counted as imaginary part

Comment: I'm sorry, but I've got to head out. Hopefully Martin can help you. Good luck!

Comment: i don't understand the imaginary part... when I look at i) and search for the imaginary, it ends with a(z) = x^2 - y^2 (+/- iy) with iy= 0? is that not correct?

Comment: $$\frac{\partial v(x, y)}{\partial x} = \pm 2y
\\ \implies v(x, y) = \pm 2xy + f(y)
\\\frac{\partial v(x, y)}{\partial y} = 2x
\\ \implies  \pm 2x + f'(y)= 2x
 $$
in one case $f(y)$ has no solution hence $v(x,y)$ does not exist, in the other $f(y)$  could be any constant so  $v(x,y)$ does exist.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the information you gave in the comments section, i *assume* that the exercise’s question migth be rewritten as:

Figure out if the real-valued functions $\{a;b\}:\mathbb{C\rightarrow R}$, given by:
\begin{array}
\\a(z)=x^2-y^2
\\b(z)=x^2+y^2
\end{array}
with $z=x+yi$, can be the real part $\Re(f)$ of a complex function $f:\mathbb{C\rightarrow C}$.

With these premises, the exercise has a defined answer:
Let $f_a$ and $f_b$ be complex functions. If we let:
$$f_a(z)=z^2=x^2-y^2+2xyi$$
We see that $\Re(f_a)=a$, so $f_a$ exists.
Likewise, if we let:
$$f_b(z)=|z|=z\overline{z}=x^2+y^2$$
Wich is it’s own real part, so $f_b$ exists too. In other words both $a$ and $b$ can be the real part of a complex function $f:\mathbb{C\rightarrow C}$.

As for the cauchy-riemann equations, you’re using them the wrong way. For the equations to work, you need the initial function $f(z)$ to be able to decompose to the form:
$$f(z)=u(x;y)+iv(x;y)$$

Comment: Hmm, because the CR equations were mentioned, I think we all assumed the function was supposed to be analytic. But I see that that's not a requirement that is stated. In which case $f_a(z) = Re(z)^2 - Im(z)^2+0i$ works just as well.

Comment: (I don't think the function I gave in my comment is a very good answer, which is why I'm betting that analyticity is a requirement, but the OP forgot to mention it. But I certainly can't be sure about that.)

Comment: I’m guessing that the OP wrote down the exercise in a form that differs from the original source. He mentions equations from $X$ to $Y$ $(X\rightarrow Y)$, but equations do no possess a domain or codomain themselves.

Comment: I promise I copied the exercise word for word, so for Jonathan missing its analyticity ??  the only confusion i have or had from the start was that the lecturer told us one (a or b) works and the other doesn't and we are on topic of the CR-Equation, thats why I thought it was important to solve the excercise with these...

Comment: Well… it is still an ill-stated excercise. As i mentioned on my earlier comment, there is no such thing as an equation with domain and image (this is, an *equation* $(X\rightarrow Y)$ does not make sense). If you interpret the word “equation” to be “function” whenever this problem appears, (wich is a more or less legit interpretation), you are only left with a problem of existence of the functions $f_a$ and $f_b$ mentioned on the answer.

Comment: i will come back if i know the answers!

Comment: So bascially I was supposed to differentiate the function a(z) with respect to x (parallel to y) two times and look if a(xx) + a(yy) = 0, which fits for a(z) but not for b(z)..